# "A required privilege is not held by the client" error when using ExcelPackage

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel

I am using [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com) to create the excel sheet through .net.

I am taking the reference at [codeplex](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20an%20Excel%20spreadsheet%20from%20scratch&referringTitle=Home) for creating excel sheet.

It is giving me following error:

```
A required privilege is not held by the client.
```

at the line when creating object of FileInfo class as

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\mynewfile.xlsx");
```

with the heading of Error "IOException was unhandled by user code."

How to resolve it ? Please help ....

Regards
Girish

Comment: Can you show us how you try to create the Excel file??

Comment: have you tried some other directory? Maybe you just don't have write access to the root of the C:\ drive on your computer (e.g. under Vista or such)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com) in production environment and haven't got into any problem. Please  give required permissions to on the folder to authenticated users or the user account (aspnet?) under which the process is running.